# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS hangs up every time with AMD GPU

Tags: 18.04

I have recently installed 18.04 LTS ubuntu in my laptop. I am facing this issue every day. My laptop hangs up after few hours of usage , nothing is working, not even mouse and keyboard. I have run `dist-upgrade` and have installed graphic driver, nothing works.

Need help

**EDIT**

As suggested by @ElderGeek . I have installed `lm-sensors` . i have seen temperature between 43 to 48 degree Celsius.

Also here is my system information:

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~$ sudo lshw -short
[sudo] password for ajit-soman: 
H/W path      Device      Class       Description
=================================================
                          system      X542BA
/0                        bus         X542BA
/0/0                      memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                      memory      160KiB L1 cache
/0/5                      memory      1MiB L2 cache
/0/28                     memory      8GiB System Memory
/0/28/0                   memory      4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (U
/0/28/1                   memory      4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (U
/0/30                     processor   AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+
/0/100                    bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root
/0/100/0.2                generic     Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Man
/0/100/1                  display     Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
/0/100/1.1                multimedia  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
/0/100/2.2                bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root
/0/100/2.2/0  wlp1s0      network     QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/2.3                bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root
/0/100/2.3/0  enp2s0      network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethe
/0/100/2.4                bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root
/0/100/2.4/0              storage     ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
/0/100/8                  generic     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/9.2                multimedia  Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controll
/0/100/10                 bus         FCH USB XHCI Controller
/0/100/11                 storage     FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/12                 bus         FCH USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/14                 bus         FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3               bridge      FCH LPC Bridge
/0/100/14.7               generic     FCH SD Flash Controller
/0/101                    bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
/0/102                    bridge      Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
/0/103                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/104                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/105                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/106                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/107                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/108                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/109                    bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/1          scsi0       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk        1TB ST1000LM035-1RK1
/0/1/0.0.0/1              volume      511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2  /dev/sda2   volume      931GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2          scsi1       storage     
/0/2/0.0.0    /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GUE1N
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~$
```

And here is `uname -a` output

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~$ uname -a
Linux ajitsoman-X542BA 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~$
```

**EDIT**

As sugested by @WinEunuuchs2Unix. I have run `journalctl -b-1` and found these red color lines. I have copy pasted one by one below:

```
Jun 12 22:10:23 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0xe frozen Jun 12 22:10:23 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2: ACPI event

Jun 12 22:22:47 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ACPI Error: [^^^PB2_.VGA_.AFN7] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)

Jun 12 22:22:47 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.VGA.LCDD._BCM, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550
Jun 12 22:22:47 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20170831/video-364)

Jun 12 22:22:47 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: [drm:hwss_wait_for_blank_complete [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: failed to blank crtc!


Jun 12 22:23:09 ajitsoman-X542BA bluetoothd[781]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)


Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd00000


Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA rtkit-daemon[973]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0xe frozen
Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2.00: ACPI event
Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 10 pio 16392 in
                                                  Get event status notification 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00res 50/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00
Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
Jun 12 23:39:54 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2: hard resetting link


Jun 13 00:01:53 ajitsoman-X542BA gdm3[840]: GLib: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

Jun 13 00:01:53 ajitsoman-X542BA gdm3[840]: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
```

Comment: If it works fine for a few hours and then hangs up, this sounds like an overheat condition to me. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature) will likely be useful.

Comment: @ElderGeek . I have recently purchased a AMD laptop . some of the laptop vendor said, you should purchase intel laptop . they said AMD laptop has heating issues.  I have added my system information above

Comment: Newer AMD chips don't currently have temperature monitor support built into the kernel. There's been some work done recently in that direction according to https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Zen-Temps-Hwmon-Next but it appears the reviews are mixed. https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/977925-amd-zen-temperature-monitoring-on-linux-is-working-with-hwmon-next I have yet to find a working temperature monitoring system for recent AMD chips. (I have an A10 here)

Comment: @ElderGeek I have installed `lm-sensors `. i have seen temperature between 43 to 48 degree Celsius

Comment: Please [edit] your comment into your post as your results are relevant to your question. Your temperatures don't appear to be the problem as your CPU has Max. operating temperature, 90 °C.  Please also [edit] the output of `uname -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### June 14, 2018 Update

Based on this ArchLinux [forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234578) it appears you need to add:

```
amdgpu.dc=0
```

to your `/etc/default/grub` LINUX line after `quiet splash`. Then run `sudo update-grub`.

---

Being a new install of Ubuntu 18.04 you are one of the lucky ones that can use `journalctl` to look at the last boot (which locked up). Use:

```
journalctl -b-1
```

Then press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to jump to EOF (End Of File). In my successful last boot it says:

```
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/d...
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/rick/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[648]: Unmounting /dev/nvme0n1p8 (Shared_WSL+Linux)
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[648]: Permissions cache : 21 writes, 4033288 reads, 99.9% hits
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/rick/casper-rw.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/e.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[736]: Unmounting /dev/sda3 (HGST_Win10)
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[736]: Permissions cache : 754 writes, 4108560 reads, 99.9% hits
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[637]: Unmounting /dev/nvme0n1p4 (NVMe_Win10)
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien ntfs-3g[637]: Permissions cache : 987 writes, 4983239 reads, 99.9% hits
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/d.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/c.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpartlabel-Basic\x5cx20data\x5cx20partition.device: Dev dev-
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 18665 (plymouthd).
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Reboot Screen.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Starting Reboot...
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien kernel: systemd-shutdow: 36 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien dnsmasq[1393]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Jun 10 16:18:51 alien systemd-journald[288]: Journal stopped
lines 46804-46832/46832 (END)
```

In yours you need to look for error messages.

You may have to use the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> key to see them.

When you have found what you are looking for (or have given up looking) press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit.

If overheating was causing the shutdown you can install Intel Powerclamp: [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872)

Besides `lm-sensors` you can get temperature readings for all thermal zones directly from the command line using this one-liner:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'

INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
SEN1             44.0°C
SEN2             52.0°C
SEN3             64.0°C
SEN4             59.0°C
B0D4             73.0°C
pch_skylake      76.5°C
x86_pkg_temp     73.0°C
```

Reported in Celsius and drop the last three zeros.

Comment: I have added output of `journalctl -b-1` command in my question. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I glanced at your output over the phone. The last entry is midnight this morning but when time did the machine actually die at?

Comment: I faced the issue around 10:30 PM yesterday

Comment: Sounds like you rebooted twice since so need to use `journalctl -b-2`

Comment: I have seen this line in output of command -journalctl -b-2 – :

`Jun 12 22:10:23 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0xe frozen
Jun 12 22:10:23 ajitsoman-X542BA kernel: ata2: ACPI event`

Comment: Can you edit your question and put your last comment into it?

Comment: I have added it to my question

Comment: The edit was helpful and I've updated the answer.

Comment: just like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dc=0"`

Comment: Looks good to me. I don't have AMD so could not test.

Comment: It works, I did not face issue even after 2.5 hours

Comment: That's wonderful. I think if you edit your title and insert "with AMD GPU" somewhere, it will help others find the solution easier.

Comment: Sure, will add this text

Answer (score 1):

in addition to solution with amdgpu.dc=0 kernel option, upgrade to ubuntu 18.10 kernel based on linux 4.18 has fixed this issue and no longer requires this amdgpu.dc=0 parameter in kernel boot for graphics to work correctly. (AMD Stoney hardware)

Answer (score -2):

Kernel is installed, right ?  ;-)

Determine which kernel-version you have with:

> uname -ar

Then search for suiting packages of kernel-headers.
The kernel-headers should have the same version, and then install the kernel-headers.

You can type too in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
>
> reboot

This should after reboot have the effect, that Linux crashes less.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix -... here is an answer, why Header files are necessary. And Linux really crashes less than before. So dont downvote me... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47330/what-exactly-are-linux-kernel-headers